# Where are the Tab Bar Item images in the XCode 5 Tabbed App template?

Tags: xcode5

XCode newbie: In XCode's Tabbed Application Template the Attributes Inspector for the two sample Tab Bar Items has values "First" and "Second" for both the title and the image.  I added a third view and entered "Third" for both - which not surprisingly shows up with a blank image.   Where do the "First" and "Second" images (a square and a circle) come from and where do I put new ones ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images are in Images.xcassets.  The template starts out with four items: AppIcon, first, LaunchImage, and second.  The entries "first" and "second" are the square and circle. In storyboard, the attributes inspector for the tab bar item (in each view controller) contains both the title text and the id of the Images.xcassets image to use for the icon - so initially these are "First" (title) and "first" (images.xcassets id) for the first view controller and similarly for the second view controller.

You can delete these and right click the image listing to add new Image Sets, each of which takes a pair of images - which for the tab bar should be a 30pt & 60pt *.png image.  By default the silhouette of the image will appear, but if you want the image in living color then you can change the UIImageRendering mode property of the corresponding UITab as follows (I tied this from the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of the main app delegate):

```
UITabBarController* tbc = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
for (int i=0; i < tbc.viewControllers.count; i++)
{
    UIViewController* vc = tbc.viewControllers[i];
    UITabBarItem* tbi    = vc.tabBarItem;
    UIImage*      img    = [tbi.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    tbi.SelectedImage = img;
}
```

For custom icons, make use of Preview's "instant alpha" tool (looks like a magic wand on the toolbar) - easy way to erase the unwanted pixels around the edges so the icon shows up as a real shape - and not a box with a shape inside.